# Allowing only one item to be selected in Dynamically Created CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

So I have a **dynamically** Created *CheckedListBox* In my WinForm(c#) and I wonder how can I allow only one Item to be selected at once.

I have already written the following :

```
checkOnClick = true;
SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One;
```

I have also Seen This method:

```
     private void  checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e) {
      for (int ix = 0; ix < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; ++ix)
        if (ix != e.Index) checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(ix, false);
    }
```

However,as CheckedListBox is dynamically created , A checkedListBox doesn't "exist" until i run the program, so I can't use void

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Sounds like a radio button group may be a better option?

Comment: I don't think so .. sometimes  i need to allow to check only 2 or 3 of the items

Comment: Selected is not the same as Checked.  SelectionMode.One wont prevent more than one thing to be checked.  And void has nothing to do with it; you could attach that handler after you create the control

Comment: Can you post code on how you create that control?

Comment: Actually do that please ,Plutonix

Comment: @Plutonix can you write how to do that ?

Comment: just hook it up to the handler when you create it: `myCLB.ItemCheck += new ItemCheckEventHandler(this.myCLB_ItemCheck);`